# Android ImageView invisible while touching

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a button with an ImageView as overlay. The ImageView is not clickable so I can still use the button. Strangely the not clickable ImageView turns invisible when I touch the button and appears again when I release it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonMailLayout"
    android:layout_width="208dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/metal"
        android:text="Write Mail"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/email20"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="64dp"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I work with:

```
Button buttonMail = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonMail);

buttonMail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Mail to : " + p._email,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? Could it have something to do with the elevation? I had to add 2dp elevation to my ImageView on 5.1 to get it in front of the button.

Comment: can you the post the code where you work with the `ImageView`?

Comment: Perhaps you should use FrameLayout.

Comment: and what do you intend to do exactly?

Comment: I added the code. I do not interact with my ImageView at all.
I simply want to use the button as a normal button but display an image I can change in front of it.

Comment: @waqaslam I'll try FrameLayout. Will report

Comment: FrameLayout has the same problem. My ImageView disappears as long as I touch my button. (Using Nexus 10 Android 5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its the button default elevation behaviour in 5.0 and above versions causing this issue, try placing your button in separate layout this way and it should work:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/buttonMailLayout"
android:layout_width="208dp"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<FrameLayout    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/metal"
        android:text="Write Mail"
        android:textSize="32dp"         
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
</FrameLayout>  
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageMail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/email20"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="64dp"
    android:clickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```